# Change Radio Button selected item text during post back using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a Radio button list like this code in an `update panel`:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Width="233px" 
                ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" 
                onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want when user clicks on any item of this radio buttons a `Please Wait...` text show instead of radio button text.I write this code :

```
function pageLoad() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#RadioButtonList1').on("change", function () {
                $("#RadioButtonList1 input:checked").val("Please Wait...");
            });
       });
    }
```

but it does not work.Where is my mistake?

thanks

Comment: Remember to check if the Ids of the readiobuttonList are correct, as when a server control is render the ids vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this code:

```
$("#RadioButtonList1 input:checked").val("Please Wait...");

to

$("#RadioButtonList1 input:checked").parent().find('label').text("Please Wait");
```

Answer (score 1):

`radio` button values are not displayed on the browser viewport, you should use `label`s and change their texts:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#RadioButtonList1').on("change", function () {
                $("#RadioButtonList1 input:checked").closest("label").text("Please Wait...");
            });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the function call and simply have this in your javascript code block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#RadioButtonList1').on("change", function () {
        $("#RadioButtonList1 input:checked").val("Please Wait...");
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function pageLoad() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').on("change", function () {
               $("#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>").find("input[checked]").val("Please Wait...");
            });
       });
    }
```